Inflationary Expansion and Vacuum Energy
During inflationary expansion, the spatial dimensions of the spacetime metric each expand by a factor of $10^{26}$ in $10^{-32}$ seconds. This super-luminal expansion from a universe radius of $3\times 10^{-24}$ meters is allowed by general relativity. My question is why does it not take any time for the vacuum energy to develop for this new space? It seems that fundamental force quantum field development and quantization would be limited by the speed of light.

why does it not take any time A short time is not no time.

By "develop" are you asking why the vacuum energy seemed to expand to fill this space instantaneously?

Yes. I am wondering why the vacuum energy was not limited by the speed of light to fill the space

Alright, that is an answerable (and good, imo) question.

If it's an intrinsic property of space, there'd be no problem, no? It would be like asking why the laws of physics can "expand superluminally".

I doubt that makes logical sense, as Big Bang theory already states that dark energy is an intrinsic property of space to account for the vacuum energy.

It seems that in the early Universe the vacuum energy spread to a very large region of space very quickly (superluminally). But in fact, the vacuum energy - and all energy - didn't "spread out" into any space at all. It was not that the Universe was an expanding sphere, and the energy had to expand to fill the sphere too. The energy was already everywhere - every point $p=(x,y,z)$ already had energy at it - and the "expansion" was just the distance between all points $p_1,p_2$ spontaneously increasing.
A very common misconception about the Big Bang and expansion is that the Universe started as a little ball and inflated like a balloon to fill an empty void. That is, like many other scientific explanations, is almost right. We weren't in the balloon when it inflated, we were on its surface. Imagine putting a bunch of tiny little dots all over the surface of an uninflated balloon, and then blowing it up. The dots didn't need to move, they were already "in place", but indeed the distance between them went up as measured on the surface of the balloon. This phenomenon - distances appearing to increase over time - is what cosmic inflation actually is.
Here, the dots on the balloon are vacuum energy quanta/really anything, and the balloon is spacetime. As it inflates, the energy was already there, everywhere, across all space; the balloon is just inflating.
Dark energy, i.e. vacuum energy produced by a cosmological constant, is interesting because its density doesn't go down as the Universe expands. This is a property of dark energy satisfying $w=\frac{p}{\rho}=-1$. Regular matter has a different equation of state depending on its type, but that's really the only departure from reality that this analogy makes. (Think of it as more dots appearing to fill the space between the original dots on the balloon - doesn't make much sense, but that's dark energy for ya. This is also why inflation is exponential.)

Vacuum energy is produced by quantum fields that exist in spacetime, and these quantum fields must be quantized at every point in space. This does not mean that the quantum field energy only exists at the space points. When the distances between space points increase superluminally by a factor of 10^26 during inflationary expansion, it seems ct time would be required for the quantum field to expand correspondingly to reestablish a continuous quantum field before it can be re-quantized.
Or, does the quantum field also expand superluminally with the inflationary expansion of space?

I think you’re still misunderstanding “expansion”. For every spatial point $p$ in spacetime, the quantum fields already exist there before expansion begins. When expansion starts happening, no new points come into existence that needs to be “filled” or “expanded into”. Every point $p$ is still there in spacetime at the same position after inflation, and the quantum fields that occupied each point $p$ before inflation starts still occupy it after inflation ends.

I understand that no new space points are created by expansion, and that the quantum fields already exist before expansion begins.
I interpret your comment that "Every point p is still there in spacetime at the same position after inflation" to mean the same (x,y,z) position, but that the absolute scales of the axes have increased by the amount of the linear expansion, e.g, 10^26.
I also interpret your comments to mean that space includes both the space points and their associated quantized quantum fields, such that the expansion of space requires the expansion of both.

"the absolute scales of the axes have increased by the amount of the linear expansion, e.g, 10^26" - that's a bad way to think about it. It's not that the axes or anything about the manifold itself has changed - we're still talking about the exact same $\mathbb{R}^4$ spacetime before and after - but the way we measure the spacetime interval between events on that manifold has changed.

I thought that comment was consistent with your comment, "the "expansion" was just the distance between all points p1,p2 spontaneously increasing", but clearly, my (general relativity) understanding needs improvement. Any suggestion on what to read to understand your last sentence would be appreciated.

The best textbook I've known for introductory GR is Gravitation. Specifically relating to FLRW and expansion/inflation, I know not of any particular text that is better than any others. Unless I'm terribly mistaken Gravitation has a section on it as well. The distance between points increasing and the coming-into-existence of points that need filling by material is quite different in a GR context.

Upon further review, (i) I concur with your comments, if they are based on comoving coordinates, and (ii) that expansion is quantified via the scale factor, a. Let me know if I am on the right track.
